# Does Namenode know the job submitted by client in HDFS multi node system?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

When client submits a job, task tracker receives it. Can Namenode sees the code of this submitted job?

Comment: I have added an answer to your query, kindly check.

Answer (score 0):

Task Tracker doesn't exist in Hadoop2 / YARN, but no, the code is not running within the Namenode process.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is **No**.

The long answer is that `namenode` do not execute the `mapreduce` program, so name node has nothing to do with the `mapreduce` **code**. The `mapreduce` jar is physically uploaded to the each node responsible to execute the `map/reduce.` So, basically only those nodes which are executing the `mapreduce` refers to the jar. The only role of `namenode` is to make sure that the jars are written to the nodes responsible for executing `map/reduce`.